# Редактор для работы с текстом

Tags: c++builder, windows

Уважаемые пользователи форума. Помогите, пожалуйста, подскажите многострочный редактор который сможет открыть и текст, и картинку.

Comment: Наверно надо использовать OLE

Answer (score 1):

TRichEdit? принимает rtf, в rtf'е картинки можно.
Описание rtf формата можно взять [отсюда](http://www.rsdn.ru/File/4783/rtfspec.zip).
Найти как вставить картинку в него можно [здесь](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showpost.php?p=29105&postcount=3).

Ещё можно использовать бесплатную библиотеку [JVCL](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/) компонент TJvRichEdit вроде.

Вообще чаще пользуйтесь поиском, исчерпывающее объяснение можно найти [здесь](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=679129).

Comment: А как вы пытаетесь вставить в него картинку?

Comment: Картинки находятся в текстовом документе вместе с текстом
 
    RichEdit1->Lines->LoadFromFile("Doc.rtf");

При помощи этого кода я могу открыть только текст, а картинку пропускает. Помогите, пожалуйста, чем сможете.

Comment: Может это поможет? RichEdit1->PlainText=false;

Comment: Может эта ссылка поможет?
http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-builder/thread47286.html

Comment: там идет работа с гиперссылкой да и я пишу в c++

Comment: Где там? Я добавил много ссылок в ответе. Принципиального отличия между дельфи и c++ Builder - нету. Вы хотите чтобы за вас написали код? Используйте компонент из JVCL.